# With BCM4313 I have wifi but no Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom, acer

Acer Aspire v5 121 with BCM4313 wifi adapter (with Bluetooth). I've tried everything I found, but nothing has worked.

The adapter doesn't show up on `lsusb`.

I already tried to find the PID of the wireless card on firmware with same results

`rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b336 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg`:

```
root@noel-Aspire-V5-121:/home/noel/Descargas# dmesg | grep Blue
[   12.279876] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.279943] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.279956] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.279962] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.279974] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   64.362777] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   64.362784] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   64.362799] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`dmesg | grep -i blue; lspci`:

```
root@noel-Aspire-V5-121:~# dmesg | grep -i blue; lspci
[   12.279876] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   12.279943] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.279956] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.279962] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.279974] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   64.362777] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   64.362784] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   64.362799] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler [Radeon HD 7290]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: There is no bluetooth.

Comment: With win8 have bluetooth, the bcm4313 is a combo card (wifi+bluetooth)

Comment: @Noelalà Your last edit removed the last unclear thing. I voted to reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: And post close, with no answer, i still with the problem, without any help, thanks!